# Obtain ID of just-built image

Tags: makefile, docker

I have a Makefile that runs `docker build -t $REPOSITORY:$VERSION .` -- this works fine. Now I would like to automate adding `latest` tag to the built image.

The command to do this is: `docker tag $IMAGE_ID latest`

How to programatically obtain the image ID, i.e. the ID of the image I just built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$IMAGE_ID` does not actually have to be an image ID. If you know the image name (which will probably be `$REPOSITORY:$VERSION` in your case), that will suffice for the [`docker tag` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

```
$ docker tag $REPOSITORY:$VERSION $REPOSITORY:latest
```

However, note that the 2nd argument to `docker tag` still needs the image name; only specifying the tag is not sufficient (when specifying only `latest`, you will end up with an image named `latest:latest`).

---

To answer your question literally, you can use the `docker images` command to obtain the ID of an image with a known name:

```
$ IMAGE_ID=$(docker images -q $REPOSITORY:$VERSION)
```

Or alternatively, to just get the *newest of all images*:

```
$ IMAGE_ID=$(docker images -q | head -1)
```